# How to connect iPhone/Android mobile via USB using nodejs/Electron?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, usb, electron

I've to connect/detect iPhone/Android mobile connected with PC through USB and perform some operations like reboot device and perform a format.

It's a cross-platform desktop app, for which I'll use [electron](http://electron.atom.io/)

I've researched a little bit and find out there's a library called [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) which can be used for connection with iOS. But I couldn't find any wrapper or library for NodeJS or Electron.

And also don't have any clue on how to do the same with Android.

Please help me with this. :)

Thanks.

Comment: hi, I am working on something very similar, have you figured this out? what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Any update on this?